# Resize text in UIButtons in Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am resizing text in 4 of the same type of buttons depending on device width on `viewDidLoad`. They are in a horizontal stack view. What are ways to do this more elegantly?

```
// resize main buttons
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width

        if screenWidth <= 320 {
            mainLockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
            mainUnlockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
            mainSplitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
            mainRoundButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
        } else if screenWidth <= 375 {
            mainLockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
            mainUnlockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
            mainSplitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
            mainRoundButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
        } else {
            mainLockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
            mainUnlockButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
            mainSplitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
            mainRoundButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but looks much better

```
  let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
  let buttons = [mainLockButton, mainUnlockButton, mainSplitButton, mainRoundButton]

  buttons.forEach {
    if screenWidth <= 320 {
        $0.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
    } else if screenWidth <= 375 {
        $0.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
    } else {
        $0.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fontSize: CGFloat {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    switch screenWidth {
    case _ where screenWidth <= 320: return 12
    case _ where screenWidth <= 375: return 13
    default: return 14
    }
}

stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
    if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium)
    }
}
```